# Using same git repository by multiple users

Tags: git, identity, git-config

As far as I know, only a single user's identity may be specified with git config. I have a situation where I'd like to have multiple identities for the same git repository, depending on the UNIX user.

The repository is at /var/www. When user jack makes a commit to it, the commit should automatically be jack's identity. When user jill makes a commit, jill's identity should be used.

The reason why I want to use the same repository is because it's the content of a website, and Apache is looking in /var/www. The contents are NOT user-specific, so using Apache's userdir feature is not an option here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every UNIX user has its own home directory.
Therefore, every UNIX user can have its own git config file (~/.gitconfig).
Then, every UNIX user can commit on shared repository with their own identity.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know git respects a user-specific file in ~/.gitconfig.

Answer (score 0):

A good way of doing this is by setting the user his email inside the .git/config file for a particular git repository as follows:

```
    git config user.name "Your Name Here"
    git config user.email your@email.com
```

Comment: Does this set repo/.git/config or rather ~/.gitconfig?

Comment: Turns out this will put user info in repo/.git/config, which is not what I want.