# What's the git equivalent of hg commit -u?

Tags: git, mercurial

I'm logged in on a shared account and want to commit some change quickly under my own identity.

With Mercurial I would do it with the `-u` flag

> -u --user USER           record the specified user as committer

```
hg commit -u 'john.doe@example.com'
```

I tried

```
git commit --author='John Doe <john.doe@example.com>'
```

but doesn't help.

Since the account is shared, this doesn't help
[Using same git repository by multiple users](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31583954/383793)

Is using `git config` and then removing it when I'm done really the only way?

Comment: While `--author` *does* work (it sets the commit's *author*), it does not change the commit's *committer*.  To set both, see Vampire's answer below (http://stackoverflow.com/a/42350173/1256452). Note that Mercurial does not have separate author and committer, just author.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `-c` you can override any Git config setting on the commandline. So just do it like

```
git -c user.name="John Doe" -c user.email=john.doe@example.com commit
```

Comment: Thanks. I suspected a way to pass config options from the command line. I just looked in the wrong place. `man git` reveals what `git help commit` didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Commit normally and then amend with the author:

```
git commit --amend --author="Author Name <email@example.org>"
```

Comment: But commit normally nags I need to config `user.name` and `user.email`. Is there a simple quick way around that?

Comment: Set a default one and do this for the ones which aren't default.

Answer (score 0):

So the other option other than what @pedro indicated is to update your git config(especially if you want to commit more).

```
git config user.name "Your Name Here" 
git config user.email your@email.com
```

if git cannot recognize your email, you will have to follow the below to add the email to your git identity.
https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-commits-linked-to-the-wrong-user/